# docker-compose failed to open letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf file in nginx.conf

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I am having problems with Docker Compose.

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  backend:
    ...
  frontend:
    ...
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: on-failure
volumes:
  db:
```

My `nginx.conf` file looks like this:

```
events {
}
http {
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  server {
    server_name barrymichaeldoyle.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://frontend:8080;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://backend:17001;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/barrymichaeldoyle.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/barrymichaeldoyle.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
  }
}
```

I just expected this to work (it was working before I attempted to enable SSL).

Instead I get the following error:

[image: docker-compose error]

Any idea what's going on? I assume it's something to do with my `volumes` where `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` can't be accessed but I have no idea how to include that in the container.

I've tried a bunch of variations around `volumes` in the `docker-compose` file but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy, you'd need to mount the files from outside your container (your host) into your container, that is what the `volumes` do (oversimplyfied).

Some like this, provied these files are on your host in that location, else your paths may differ.

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf # you already linked your config
  - /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf # link tls config
  - /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem # link params
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/certname:/etc/letsencrypt/live/certname # link the cert folder
```

You will need to change `certname` obliviously.

([docker volumes reference](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/))